Is there $W$ that satisfy $D(W(D(W(M))^{-1}.M.D(W(M^t))^{-1}))=I$?
Given the matrix function with $\odot$ (Hadamard/Schur/element-wise) and $\otimes$ (Kronecker) products
$\begin{matrix}
D: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \hfill \\
v_n \mapsto ( v_{n \times 1} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}_{1 \times n} ) \odot I = \\
\quad
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & v_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & v_3 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & v_n
\end{bmatrix}$
the operation $D(w)^{-1}.M$ output is a matrix $M_{m\times n}$ and a vector $w_m$  (of line weights of $M$) being used to obtain the matrix $M$ balanced according to $w$, after all
$D(w)^{-1}.M = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{M_{1,1}}{w_{1}} & \frac{M_{1,2}}{w_{1}} & \frac{M_{1,3}}{w_{1}} & \cdots & \frac{M_{1,n}}{w_{1}} \\
\frac{M_{2,1}}{w_{2}} & \frac{M_{2,2}}{w_{2}} & \frac{M_{2,3}}{w_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{M_{2,n}}{w_{2}} \\
\frac{M_{3,1}}{w_{3}} & \frac{M_{3,2}}{w_{3}} & \frac{M_{3,3}}{w_{3}} & \cdots & \frac{M_{3,n}}{w_{3}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{M_{m,1}}{w_{m}} & \frac{M_{m,2}}{w_{m}} & \frac{M_{m,3}}{w_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{M_{m,n}}{w_{m}}
\end{bmatrix},$
and similarly $M.D(\omega)^{-1}$ is $M_{m\times n}$ and $\omega_n$ (of column weights of $M$) to get $M$ balanced according to $\omega$. If $(w,\omega)=(W(M),W(M^t))$ such that the matrix function $W$ obtains the vector of line weights, therefore of columns when calculated from the transposed matrix,
is there a non trivial pattern of functions $W$ that satisfy $D(W(D(w)^{-1}.M.D(\omega)^{-1}))=I$? Preferably a pattern of formulas that can be calculated in $O(m_{^{\space \times}} n)$ operations. I won't complain about expected exceptions like division by zero.

What if $w_i=0$ for any $i$?

My point is that everything youve done after the first step doesnt make sense if $v$ has any component which is zero.

It's like $?/0$, a zero row can have weight zero or $NaN$ and I won't complain about expected exceptions.

Given
$\begin{matrix}
N_p: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}^m \hfill \\
\hfill M_{m \times n} & \mapsto & \begin{bmatrix}
||M_{1,_{^\cdots}}||_p \\
||M_{2,_{^\cdots}}||_p \\
||M_{3,_{^\cdots}}||_p \\
\vdots \\
||M_{m,_{^\cdots}}||_p 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}$
probably the function
$\begin{matrix}
W: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}^m \hfill \\
\hfill M_{m \times n} & \mapsto & N_\infty(M . D(N_\infty(M^t))^{-1})
\end{matrix}$
is such that $D(W(D(w)^{-1}.M.D(\omega)^{-1}))=I$ when $M$ doesn't have row(s) of zeros and column(s) of zeros ($N_p(M)$ doesn't have zero(s) and $N_p(M^t)$ too).
Although I (or anyone else) haven't proven it yet, we have here for Python programmers this code that tests the formulas. You can set smaller maximum matrices "row x column rank" using MaxMtxNumVals to finish faster. Using MaxMtxNumVals=16 it generates a lot of 2x8, 4x4, 8x2 and smaller matrices until 2x2.
DeltaZero = 1/(1<<204)
DeltaZero3 = DeltaZero**3
DeltaZero4 = DeltaZero**4

MaxMtxVal_per_MinMtxVal = DeltaZero
MaxMtxNumVals = 16

def Calc_W_DWMtxEm1_x_Mtx_x_DWMtxTEm1( Mtx ):
    def Calc_Ninf_Mtx( Mtx ):
        return [ max( abs(MtxVal) for MtxVal in MtxRow ) for MtxRow in Mtx ]
    def Calc_Ninf_MtxT( Mtx ):
        return [ max( abs(MtxRow[ColIndex]) for MtxRow in Mtx ) for ColIndex in range(len(Mtx[0])) ]
    def Calc_BalMtx_Rows( Mtx , Ninf_Mtx ):
        return [ [
                Mtx[RowIndex][ColIndex]/( Ninf_Mtx[RowIndex]+DeltaZero4 ) for ColIndex in range(len(Mtx[RowIndex]))
            ] for RowIndex in range(len(Mtx)) ]
    def Calc_BalMtx_Cols( Mtx , Ninf_MtxT ):
        return [ [
                MtxRow[ColIndex]/( Ninf_MtxT[ColIndex]+DeltaZero4 ) for ColIndex in range(len(Mtx[0]))
            ] for MtxRow in Mtx ]
    def Calc_W_Mtx(Mtx):
        return Calc_Ninf_Mtx(Calc_BalMtx_Cols(Mtx, Calc_Ninf_MtxT(Mtx)))
    W_Mtx, W_MtxT = Calc_W_Mtx(Mtx), Calc_Ninf_MtxT(Calc_BalMtx_Rows(Mtx, Calc_Ninf_Mtx(Mtx)))
    return Calc_W_Mtx( Calc_BalMtx_Cols(Calc_BalMtx_Rows(Mtx, W_Mtx), W_MtxT) )

ValsList, MtxsNumVals = [DeltaZero3, 1, MaxMtxVal_per_MinMtxVal], 0
for MtxNumVals in range(4, MaxMtxNumVals+1):
    for MtxNumCols in range(2, MtxNumVals//2+1):
        if MtxNumVals%MtxNumCols>0: continue
        MtxsNumVals += MtxNumVals*round(len(ValsList)**(MtxNumVals-1))
Hundred_Per_NumMtxsVals, MtxsNumVals, MtxDims_MaxErrors = 100/MtxsNumVals, 1/512, []
MustPrintErrors, PrintedSomeProgress, MtxDims_GrMaxError = False, False, ([],0)
for MtxNumVals in range(4, MaxMtxNumVals+1):
    for MtxNumCols in range(2, MtxNumVals//2+1):
        if MtxNumVals%MtxNumCols>0: continue
        MtxDims_MaxError = 0
        MtxNumRows = MtxNumVals//MtxNumCols
        for MtxFctsCode in range(len(ValsList)-2, round(len(ValsList)**MtxNumVals), len(ValsList)):
            Mtx, MtxFctsRemCode = [], MtxFctsCode
            for MtxRowIndex in range(MtxNumRows):
                MtxNewRow = []
                for MtxColIndex in range(MtxNumCols):
                    MtxNewRow += [ ValsList[MtxFctsRemCode%len(ValsList)] ]
                    MtxFctsRemCode //= len(ValsList)
                Mtx += [MtxNewRow]
            MtxDims_MaxError = max( abs(MtxWdwValue-1) for MtxWdwValue in Calc_W_DWMtxEm1_x_Mtx_x_DWMtxTEm1(Mtx)+[1+MtxDims_MaxError] )
            Temporary, MtxsNumVals = int(MtxsNumVals*Hundred_Per_NumMtxsVals), MtxsNumVals+MtxNumVals
            Temporary = Temporary, int(MtxsNumVals*Hundred_Per_NumMtxsVals)
            if Temporary[1]>Temporary[0] and Temporary[1]<100:
                print("Progress = %i%% %i/%.0f"%(Temporary[1], MtxsNumVals, 100/Hundred_Per_NumMtxsVals))
                PrintedSomeProgress = True
        MtxDims_MaxError = (["--> %ix%i: Error=%.5f %.3e"%(MtxNumRows,MtxNumCols, MtxDims_MaxError, MtxDims_MaxError)], MtxDims_MaxError)
        MtxDims_MaxErrors += [MtxDims_MaxError]
        if MtxDims_MaxError[1]>MtxDims_GrMaxError[1]:
            MtxDims_GrMaxError = ([">>> Greatest maximum error from list:"]+MtxDims_MaxError[0]+[""], MtxDims_MaxError[1])
        if (not MustPrintErrors) and PrintedSomeProgress and (MtxNumCols==MtxNumVals//2):
            MustPrintErrors = True
        if MustPrintErrors:
            print("\n>>> New maximum errors list:")
            for MtxDims_MaxError in MtxDims_MaxErrors:
                for MtxDims_MaxErrorTextRows in MtxDims_MaxError[0]:
                    print(MtxDims_MaxErrorTextRows)
            for MtxDims_MaxErrorTextRows in MtxDims_GrMaxError[0]:
                print(MtxDims_MaxErrorTextRows)

